# When I change text and show it on UI in Thread, nothing is done (JAVA)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, layout-inflater, java-threads

This code is in OnCreate in MainActivity

```
    inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    serversView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_home, null, false);
    test = serversView.findViewById(R.id.titleDescription);

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try  {


                    //some code
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            test.setText(utf8text+"mk");

                            Log.i(LOG_TAG,"serversView: "+ serversView + " test: "+ test + " test.getText().toString():"+ test.getText().toString());
                        }
                    });


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
```

Using class Thread is mandatory!
When I log `Log.i(LOG_TAG," test.getText().toString():"+ test.getText().toString());` all is ok, text is changed, but in UI nothing is done. What's problem?

UPD:
When I do so:

`runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
          textView.setText(utf8text);
          Log.i(LOG_TAG,"textView.getText: "+ textView.getText().toString());
     }
});`

and if textView is in main_activity.xml, then it changes. But how to do, for example, using LayoutInflater to get and change the TextView in another fragment/activity?

Answer (score 0):

**Add the below line inside run method**

serversView.invalidateViews();

**Forexample,**

```
public void run() {
    test.setText(utf8text+"mk");
    serversView.invalidateViews();
    Log.i(LOG_TAG,"serversView: "+ serversView + " test: "+ test + "test.getText().toString():"+ test.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: Please try using serversView.invalidate()

Answer (score 0):

The UI can not be updated by non UI thread, but android provides the android.os.Handler class or the AsyncTasks classes, below is the sample code for thread handler try it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ProgressBar progress;
private TextView text;
Handler handler;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    progress = findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    text = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    handler = new Handler();
}
public void startProgress(View view) {
    // do something long
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                final int value = i;
                doFakeWork();
                handler.post(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progress.setProgress(value);
                        if(value!=10)
                            text.setText("updated");
                        else
                            text.setText("updating");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start(); }
    // Simulating something timeconsuming
private void doFakeWork() {
    try { SystemClock.sleep(5000);} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}}}
```

Hope it helps you, Good Luck.

Comment: It doesnt help. May be need startProgress method put in OnCreate?

Comment: no above startProgress method is responding to button Click Event. I added this method in the onclick attribute of button in xml layout, Did you get any error?

Comment: I inserted this in OnCreate, but still, textview doesnt change the text in UI, but when logging - changes

Comment: Oh, I realized that you need to insert it when you click on the button, I did everything, but in the UI does not change anything as before, and when logging changes

Comment: Use thread handler UI will be updated for sure. I am Updating your code in another answer.

Comment: Yeah, when you gave me your code. Now I made Ctrl+Z before my code and it turned out that my code works, only the problem is that only on MainActivity, but how to make it so that setText can be changed by not transferring the code to fragment classes?

Comment: sorry, i didn't get it want you are trying to ask about fragment class in the code of thread??

Answer (score 0):

Thread Handler Class,Try it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView test;
Handler handle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    test = findViewById(R.id.titleDescription);
    handle = new Handler();

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            test.setText("Hey! Text Changed");
        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();

}
```

}

Comment: You can communicate data from current activity to another activity(using explicit Intent) or fragment (by setting arguments to that fragment) and then use that data in UI.